# data.table joins with on= and > or >= doesnt work and Order() function in r is not ordering correctly

Tags: r, join, data.table, rank

I want to rank the dataset `dt$myTime` between `dt.period$start_prev` and `dt.period$start`. After that I want to declare the record with 1 using the rank fucntion to filter on it later.

Unfortunately I keep running into problem, be it with the join or with the result of the rank function

My data look like this:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

start <- seq(from = dmy_hms("31.12.2013 23:59:59") + 1, to = dmy_hms("31.12.2022 23:59:59") + 1, by = "year") -1
end <- start %m+% months(12)
# Help column start_previous: So that we can later determine the most current dataset at the start.
start_prev <- start %m+% months(-12) 
month_between <- interval(start, end) %/% months(1)
dt.period <- data.table(start_prev, start, end, month_between)

dt <- data.table(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
                      , myTime = c(dmy_hms("15.12.2019 12:03:00"), dmy_hms("15.12.2019 12:03:00"), dmy_hms("18.12.2019 12:03:00")
                                   , dmy_hms("15.03.2020 03:10:00"), dmy_hms("16.03.2020 12:03:00")))
```

Cross Join over help column Hilfsspalte "z", "zmyTime", "zstart", "zstart_prev". Otherwise the column will be filled incorrectly due to the JOIN (<, >=).

```
dt.period[, `:=`(z = 1, zstart = start, zstart_prev = start_prev)] 
dt[, `:=`(zmyTime = myTime, z = 1)]
```

Question: Why do I have multiple records in `dt.left`where id is NA?
Question: Is there any other way so that I dont overwrite the "z" columns when joining due to conditional (non-equi join with <) linking? This problem is known, but how can I solve it here, because I need all columns of dt and dt.period

```
        ID              myTime          start_prev               start                 end month_between
 1: NA                <NA> 2012-12-31 23:59:59 2013-12-31 23:59:59 2014-12-31 23:59:59            12
 2: NA                <NA> 2013-12-31 23:59:59 2014-12-31 23:59:59 2015-12-31 23:59:59            12
 3: NA                <NA> 2014-12-31 23:59:59 2015-12-31 23:59:59 2016-12-31 23:59:59            12
 4: NA                <NA> 2015-12-31 23:59:59 2016-12-31 23:59:59 2017-12-31 23:59:59            12
 5: NA                <NA> 2016-12-31 23:59:59 2017-12-31 23:59:59 2018-12-31 23:59:59            12
 6: NA                <NA> 2017-12-31 23:59:59 2018-12-31 23:59:59 2019-12-31 23:59:59            12
 7:  1 2019-12-15 12:03:00 2018-12-31 23:59:59 2019-12-31 23:59:59 2020-12-31 23:59:59            12
 8:  1 2019-12-15 12:03:00 2018-12-31 23:59:59 2019-12-31 23:59:59 2020-12-31 23:59:59            12
 9:  1 2019-12-18 12:03:00 2018-12-31 23:59:59 2019-12-31 23:59:59 2020-12-31 23:59:59            12
10:  1 2020-03-15 03:10:00 2019-12-31 23:59:59 2020-12-31 23:59:59 2021-12-31 23:59:59            12
11:  1 2020-03-16 12:03:00 2019-12-31 23:59:59 2020-12-31 23:59:59 2021-12-31 23:59:59            12
12: NA                <NA> 2020-12-31 23:59:59 2021-12-31 23:59:59 2022-12-31 23:59:59            12
13: NA                <NA> 2021-12-31 23:59:59 2022-12-31 23:59:59 2023-12-31 23:59:59            12
```

```
dt.Left <-  
  dt[dt.period, on = .(z, zmyTime > zstart_prev, zmyTime <= zstart)][, `:=` (zmyTime = NULL, z = NULL, zmyTime.1 = NULL)]
```

The following statement also provides the expected amount of data

```
dt.Left_2 <- dt[dt.period, on = .(z), allow.cartesian=TRUE, nomatch = NULL][between(x=myTime, lower = start, upper = end)]
```

Now I use different variantsb of the rank function, but this one doesn't seem to work when dt$myTime has the same time. IN Line 7 and 9 the values of Rank are assigned incorrectly.
The values in line 10 and 11 are correct

```
dt.Left[, vRankOrder:= rank(order(myTime, decreasing = TRUE)), by = list(ID, start)]
dt.Left[, vSort:= sort(myTime, decreasing = TRUE), by = list(ID, start)]
dt.Left[, vOrder:= order(myTime, decreasing = TRUE), by = list(ID, start)]
dt.Left[, vOrderNumeric := rank(order(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(myTime)), decreasing = TRUE)), by = list(ID, start)] 
dt.Left[, vRankOrderNumneric := rank(order(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(myTime)), decreasing = TRUE)), by = list(ID, start)]
```

```
        ID              myTime          start_prev               start                 end month_between vRankOrder               vSort vOrder vOrderNumeric
 1: NA                <NA> 2012-12-31 23:59:59 2013-12-31 23:59:59 2014-12-31 23:59:59            12          1                <NA>      1             1
 2: NA                <NA> 2013-12-31 23:59:59 2014-12-31 23:59:59 2015-12-31 23:59:59            12          1                <NA>      1             1
 3: NA                <NA> 2014-12-31 23:59:59 2015-12-31 23:59:59 2016-12-31 23:59:59            12          1                <NA>      1             1
 4: NA                <NA> 2015-12-31 23:59:59 2016-12-31 23:59:59 2017-12-31 23:59:59            12          1                <NA>      1             1
 5: NA                <NA> 2016-12-31 23:59:59 2017-12-31 23:59:59 2018-12-31 23:59:59            12          1                <NA>      1             1
 6: NA                <NA> 2017-12-31 23:59:59 2018-12-31 23:59:59 2019-12-31 23:59:59            12          1                <NA>      1             1
 7:  1 **2019-12-15 12:03:00** 2018-12-31 23:59:59 2019-12-31 23:59:59 2020-12-31 23:59:59            12          3 2019-12-18 12:03:00      3             3
 8:  1 **2019-12-15 12:03:00** 2018-12-31 23:59:59 2019-12-31 23:59:59 2020-12-31 23:59:59            12          1 2019-12-15 12:03:00      1             1
 9:  1 **2019-12-18 12:03:00** 2018-12-31 23:59:59 2019-12-31 23:59:59 2020-12-31 23:59:59            12          2 2019-12-15 12:03:00      2             2
10:  1 2020-03-15 03:10:00 2019-12-31 23:59:59 2020-12-31 23:59:59 2021-12-31 23:59:59            12          2 2020-03-16 12:03:00      2             2
11:  1 2020-03-16 12:03:00 2019-12-31 23:59:59 2020-12-31 23:59:59 2021-12-31 23:59:59            12          1 2020-03-15 03:10:00      1             1
12: NA                <NA> 2020-12-31 23:59:59 2021-12-31 23:59:59 2022-12-31 23:59:59            12          1                <NA>      1             1
13: NA                <NA> 2021-12-31 23:59:59 2022-12-31 23:59:59 2023-12-31 23:59:59            12          1                <NA>      1             1
```

I hope someone can help me.

Best regards

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what is your actual desired output? Is it the last code block with your `**`-emphasis removed?

Comment: Hi r2evans, as output I would like the last code block. With the **-emphasis I want to show that none of the columns vRankOrder, vSort and so on gives the desired result, because the decreasing numbering is not correct.

Comment: This is what I would expect as output: `start_prev               start              myTime ID valrank
1: 2018-12-31 23:59:59 2019-12-31 23:59:59 2019-12-15 12:03:00  1     2
2: 2018-12-31 23:59:59 2019-12-31 23:59:59 2019-12-15 12:03:00  1     2
3: 2018-12-31 23:59:59 2019-12-31 23:59:59 2019-12-18 12:03:00  1     1
4: 2019-12-31 23:59:59 2020-12-31 23:59:59 2020-03-15 03:10:00  1     2
5: 2019-12-31 23:59:59 2020-12-31 23:59:59 2020-03-16 12:03:00  1     1`